# Как поместить кнопку на нижней границе правильно?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Я разместил кнопку "В корзину" на середине нижней границе карточки товара, но при уменьшении экрана она начинает уезжать.
Подскажите, как исправить. Вот мой код:

```css
.catalog__title {
    font-family: @Merri;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 4rem;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

.catalog__title::before {
    content: "";
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 12%;
}

.catalog__title::after {
    content: "";
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    right: 13%;
}

.catalog__items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -1rem 2.8rem;
    
}

.catalog__col {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.catalog__item {
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 2px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.item__img {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.catalog__item-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item__title {
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    font-family: @Merri;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 1.9rem;
    color: #000000;
}

.item__text {
    margin: .5rem 0 1rem 0;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: #343434;
}

.item__price {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000000;
}

.item__btn {
    background: #243786;
    padding: .8rem 2.5rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    min-width: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<section class="catalog">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="catalog__title">Каталог</h2>
            <div class="catalog__items">
                <div class="catalog__col">
                    <div class="catalog__item">
                        <img src="images/item-img.png" alt="item-img" class="item__img img">
                        <div class="catalog__item-content">
                            <div class="item__title">Ананасы</div>
                            <div class="item__text">Кольца в легком сиропе</div>
                            <div class="item__price">300 ₽</div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="item__btn">В корзину</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для класса .item_btn убери position: absolute; и укажи margin: 0 auto; display: block;

```
.item{ 
background: #243786;
padding: .8rem 2.5rem;
color: #ffffff;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 1.5rem;
min-width: 130px;
/* position: absolute; */
/* left: 25%; */
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;}
```

Comment: На будущее погугли что такое transform: translate, если хочешь пользоваться position: absolute;

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Все исправил